# Salesforce License Provisioning?

Tags: sandbox, licenses

Has anyone had experience of getting SFDC to provision licences directly to a sandbox without the need to refresh the box from production?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this can't be done.  At least not for license seats.  It might be possible for feature licenses.  All I can suggest is to contact your AE for help.